# Expose a Singleton to other classes using an interface

Tags: c#, design-patterns, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game in Unity C# using a *Singleton* `GameManager` and I was warned that using references of the class in other scripts like `GameManager.instance.someVar` makes the code fragile and difficult for later edit. So I looked for *how to access a singleton with interfaces* but haven't found what I was after. As I wish to code properly, I would like someone to point me to a decent source that tells me how to do so, or have him/her tell me in brief.

Comment: The singleton pattern is extremely common in gaming - information about the player, for example, is well suited to it - in what way is it _fragile_? Also provide your code so any flaws are visible (and then sources related to that flaw can be provided).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there is a general solution to this, I am not sure how feasible it will be for you.

Suppose we have a true singleton:

```
public static class Highlander //cos, there can be only one. Sorry. couldn't resist
{
   public static void Quicken(string name)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("{0} gets their quickening on",name);
   }
}
```

Suppose we want to be able to pass this around in an abstract manner, using Interfaces.

```
public interface IImmortal
{
    void Quicken();
}
```

Well, you cannot implement an interface on a static class or member, so how do you pass references to this class around by interface?

Simple - create a wrapper/adapter class which implements the interface you want:

```
public class McLeod: IImortal
{
   public void Quicken()
   {
       Highlander.Quicken("Conor");
   }
}

public class Kurgen: IImortal
{
   public void Quicken()
   {
       Highlander.Quicken("The Kurgen");
   }
}
```

Now you can pass `IImortal` around, and the wrapping implementation(s) simply call through to the Singleton. Note how the `Wrapper` can supply data to the Singleton from within itself, as above, in which case it's more like an `Adapter`. But the concept is the same.

> In the case of Unity, I don't know if this will suit, since the GameManager class likely exposes a ton of other properties and methods you would also have to wrap/adapt - it may not be worth creating wrapper interfaces for all of this, so consider perhaps that in this case you need to embrace it :)

Answer (score 0):

Singletons, being static, dont support interfaces. Perhaps your other source might mean that you should use a Factory pattern or perhaps an Inversion of Control (IOC) method. In those cases the Factory would look like `GameManagerFactory.GetGameInstance()` rather than refer to the Instance static property of a GameManager.

The true limitation of Singlton programming is in the area of unit testing - because your code is bound directly to the specific class "GameManager" you could not replace it in a unit test with another "test version" of the GameManager. To support unit testing you should try to make sure that any significant classes your code depends on could be replaced by a test version of a class, without your code caring. When using Singletons this is hard (if not impossible) to do.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I tend to create an empty GameObject, give it a proper name or a tag and attach a script component to it.

This way I can easily get a reference in any other GameObject that might need it and retrieve the script component from it.

Comment: I was also curious about what was the real purpose for this class and why the OP wanted to use the Singleton pattern specifically. Most of the times proposing a solution without exposing the problem can lead to very misleading answers.

Comment: I thought you were asking a question AND answering, that's why I removed the question part (which does not belong in an answer). If I made a mistake don't hesitate to edit again. Maybe your questions were rhetorical (in this case I would suggest to formulate these ideas differently). Thanks.

Comment: if so then you were right, I was indeed asking and answering. In this case what is the usual practice? Should I ask and then create a comment? Thanks!